# "Missing number" error with SCfigure (from sidecap package)

Tags: captions

Does anyone know how to do "side captions" in LaTeX if you already have a caption environment specified? I keep getting an error when I use `SCfigure`.

Ex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}[h!]
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{conforms}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

`SCfigure` has two optional arguments. If you use the second one, you must also use the first:

```
\begin{SCfigure}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][h!]
```